# Check if WCF(namedpipes) host is available?

Tags: wcf, exception, named-pipes

**Hi,**

We have a winform application that is only to be executed as a singelton, If a second instance try to start this new instance will connect to the current and transmit parameters over namedpipes.

The problem is that when starting the first instance there will be a try to connect to existing host. If the host is not existing(like in this case) an exception will be thrown. There is no problem to handle this exception but our developers is often using "Break on Exception" and that means that every time we startup the application the developer will get two(in this case) breaks about exception. Thay will have to hit F5 twice for every start.

Is there any way to check if the service is available without throw exception if its not?

**BestRegards**

**Edit1:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr OpenFileMapping(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, string lpName);
```

The following code says : Error 152 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'Orbit.Client.Main.Classes.Controllers.MyClientController.SafeFileMappingHandle'

```
using (SafeFileMappingHandle fileMappingHandle
                = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, false, sharedMemoryName))
            {
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is the following :

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached) 
return true;
```

This will make sure that the code for checking the service is never runned during debugging.

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 4):

If there is already a WCF server listening on the named pipe endpoint, there will be a shared memory object created, via which the server publishes the actual name of the pipe. [See here for details of this](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2010/10/20/locating-a-wcf-named-pipe-endpoint.aspx).

You can check for the existence of this shared memory object with code something like the following, which will not throw, just return false, if there is no server running already. (I've extracted this from code I already have working, and then edited it to do what you want - but without testing the edited version, so apologies if you have to fix up assembly/namespace refs etc to get it running.)

```
public static class ServiceInstanceChecker
{

    public static bool DoesAServerExistAlready(string hostName, string path)
    {
        return IsNetNamedPipeSharedMemoryMetaDataPublished(DeriveSharedMemoryName(hostName, path));
    }


    private static string DeriveSharedMemoryName(string hostName, string path)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe);
        builder.Append("://");
        builder.Append(hostName.ToUpperInvariant());
        builder.Append(path);
        byte[] uriBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

        string encodedNameRoot;
        if (uriBytes.Length >= 0x80)
        {
            using (HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                encodedNameRoot = ":H" + Convert.ToBase64String(algorithm.ComputeHash(uriBytes));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            encodedNameRoot = ":E" + Convert.ToBase64String(uriBytes);
        }
        return Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe + encodedNameRoot;
    }

    private static bool IsNetNamePipeSharedMemoryMetaDataPublished(string sharedMemoryName)
    {
        const uint FILE_MAP_READ = 0x00000004;
        const int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2;
        using (SafeFileMappingHandle fileMappingHandle 
            = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, false, sharedMemoryName))
        {
            if (fileMappingHandle.IsInvalid)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND == errorCode) return false; 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode); // The name matched, but something went wrong opening it
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class SafeFileMappingHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public SafeFileMappingHandle() : base(true) { }
        public SafeFileMappingHandle(IntPtr handle) : base(true) { base.SetHandle(handle); }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(base.handle);
        }
    }

}
```

The host name and path you pass in are derived from the WCF service url. Hostname is either a specific hostname (e.g. `localhost`) or `+`, or `*`, depending on the setting for HostNameComparisonMode.

EDIT: You'll also need a couple of P/Invoke declarations for the Win API functions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject); 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern SafeFileMappingHandle OpenFileMapping(
  uint dwDesiredAccess,
  bool inheritHandle,
  string name
);
```

EDIT2: We need to tweak the return value of DeriveSharedMemoryName to specify the Local kernel namespace, assuming that your application is not run with elevated privileges. Change the last line of this function to read:

```
return @"Local\" + Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe + encodedNameRoot;
```

You also need to specify the hostname parameter correctly to match the hostNameComparisonMode setting used in your binding. As far as I recall, this defaults to StrongWildcard matching in the NetNamedPipeBinding, so you probably need to pass in `"+"` rather than `"localhost"`.

Comment: > Thanks but I get a couple of problems here when implementing this in my code. FileRights is not known, SafeFileMappingHandle.ReleaseHandle > CloseHandle not known, IsNetNamedPipeSharedMemoryMetaDataPublished not known?

Comment: You'll need to add P/Invoke declarations for CloseHandle and OpenFileMapping - to the Win API functions of the same name.

Comment: See my edit... a syntactic trick learned from the .NET Framework implementation

Comment: Thanks! But this does not work. DoesAServerExistAlready returns false always. The paramters looks like this : DoesAServerExistAlready("localhost", "/MyService") and the channel looks like this : using (ChannelFactory<IOrbitClientController> factory = new ChannelFactory<IOrbitClientController>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyService")))

Comment: I did warn you I hadn't tested this :-) See my further edit for a quick fix. If there is a possibility that your application might run with elevated privileges so as to be able to create Global kernel objects, you'll need a further change so the code checks both Global and Local namespaces. If there is a possibility that different instances of the application could have different binding configuration, you may need to check all the variants for the hostName parameter, in case there's an instance with a different HostNameComparisonMode.

Comment: Hi, this is still not working. But a solution on my problem might be the following code : if (Debugger.IsAttached) return true;. This will make sure that the code is not executed wile dubugging but then I start from the exe it will run the propper code.

Comment: A simple way is to check if the proxy on the client side can be opened.  See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571093/how-can-i-test-to-see-if-a-net-pipe-service-is-listening]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to list the named pipes available using

`String[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\.\pipe\");`

and then determine is your named pipe is amongst them?

Comment: This has no hope of success, because his code will not know what pipe name to look for. The pipe name changes every time the service is opened.