# How can I test to see if a net pipe service is listening

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

How can I test programmatically to see if a particular net pipe service is running and listening, so I don't get a "There was no endpoint listening at..." exception?

So for instance if I have this code:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/something");
var _ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Automation), new Uri[] { baseAddress });
NetNamedPipeBinding nnpb = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAutomation), nnpb, "ImListening");
_ServiceHost.Open();
```

I want from another application communicate with `http://localhost/something/ImListening` but before I want to make sure is listening so I don't get an exception, or is the exception the only way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the exception. That *is* the proper way to do it.

Comment: The thing is that I actually need to _wait_ for this service since I'll be launching it from the same code that will communicate with it, so should I just create some dummy method in my service and keep calling it until I stop getting an exception?

Comment: Unless you're sending a lot of data to your service, why not just contact the method you're trying to contact in the first place? (with delayed repetition on exception, obviously)

Comment: Well, I don't know which methods I'll be calling on my service yet. I also want to keep the channel open unless it fails or stuff. Maybe I could use a `Mutex` here. Anyhow, I'd like my app to know if the service is already running or not. Later on this could be used to Enable / Disable some buttons and that kind of stuff.

Comment: Why would your service not be running anyway? Would that be a common situation? If not, just don't worry about it. If so, make another service that just tells you whether the first service works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions exists for a reason, I would just handle the exception, as long a you handle it the user wont get a cryptic error message, which I guess is what you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ChannelFactory.CreateChannel`, it returns a proxy that implements your service's interface without opening a communication channel. However, the proxy also implements `IClientChannel`, which you can use this to check if the endpoint is up. In my case I also needed to wait for the endpoint to start, so I used a loop with a timeout:

```
public static Interface CreateOpenChannel<Interface>(Binding protocol, EndpointAddress address, int timeoutMs = 5000)
{
    for (int startTime = Environment.TickCount;;) {
        // a proxy is unusable after comm failure ("faulted" state), so create it within the loop
        Interface proxy = ChannelFactory<Interface>.CreateChannel(protocol, address);
        try {
            ((IClientChannel) proxy).Open();
            return proxy;
        } catch (CommunicationException ex) {
            if (unchecked(Environment.TickCount - startTime) >= timeoutMs)
                throw;
            Thread.Sleep(Math.Min(1000, timeoutMs / 4));
        }
    }
}
```

This was tested with `NetNamedPipeBinding`. I am unsure whether this will behave the same way with other bindings, or whether [`Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.open?view=netframework-4.8) merely opens a connection or also tests the validity of the connection (e.g. whether the host interface matches the client interface).

Comment: +1 This is a simple reliable way that does not require any extra methods to be added to the proxy.  It checks for the Exception as per the accepted answer, but using the Open method on the proxy is the secret sauce.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is not the best way, but I not found another way to test an endpoint using `NetNamedPipe`.

I usually do this approach:

```
    public void IsValid()
    {
        RegisterConfiguration();

        var endPoints = Host.Description.Endpoints;
        if (!endPoints.HasElements())
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("endpoints (WCF Service).");
        }

        foreach (var item in endPoints)
        {
            var service = new ChannelFactory<ITcoService>(item.Binding, item.Address);
            try
            {
                var client = (IClientChannel)service.CreateChannel();

                try
                {
                    client.Open(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        string.Format(
                            "A registration already exists for URI: \"{0}\" (WCF Service is already open in some IChannelListener).",
                            item.Address));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException ||
                        ex is System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.DumpObject());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    new Action(client.Dispose).InvokeSafe();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                new Action(service.Close).InvokeSafe();
            }
        }
    }
```

(sorry the extension methods in this code, `InvokeSafe` is just a try/catch to execute a `Action` and `HasElements` just test if a collection is different of null and empty).