# Client checking if named pipe host is open

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes, inter-process-communicat

I have a self-hosted WCF service host and client both on the same machine. I've used WCF here for inter-process communication purposes. I am able to open the host and have the client connect to it after a period of time like so:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(AIEngineLoader));

string hostAddress = string.Format("net.pipe://localhost/AIEngine/" + name);
var endPointBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
endPointBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
endPointBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAIEngineLoader), endPointBinding, hostAddress);            

host.Open();
```

The host is run inside another console app. The client is able to connect to this host after waiting for some time after starting the console process(three seconds now). I don't want to have to wait a prespecified amount of time and then connect to the host. One way could be a blocking wait in a loop while catching the CreateChannel exception in the client. This solution is not elegant. Is there a way for a client to check whether or not a host is listening without resorting to exception catching?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if WCF(namedpipes) host is available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552502/check-if-wcfnamedpipes-host-is-available)

Comment: @fejesjoco The link you mention provides a solution that seems too involved. I'm not ready to complicate my code to that degree for a simple check. I would prefer a looping check to that.

Comment: in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571093/how-can-i-test-to-see-if-a-net-pipe-service-is-listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF will not simply tell you if someone is listening on that pipe address. The actual name of the pipe is [obfuscated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx), you can only try to connect and catch the exception. You could leave WCF out of the equation by using a [named global mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this is raw inter-process communication. However, WCF with pipes is itself IPC, so I wouldn't complicate matters with mutexes. It's like sending a postal mail along with a FedEx package to let the other party know that the package is on the way.